# Why are ShareFolders so slow when used with Apache on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

When I put a site on a shared folder on Virtualbox I get a very slow response time. If i move it to a non-shared folder such as my home folder it responsed instantly. I am running a Ubuntu guest on a Snow Leopard host.

Comment: What is running the server, the guest or the host?

Comment: I have the same problem. Ubuntu is the guest in my case.

Comment: I've not seen this issue running Windows guests on my Ubuntu host. I don't know where the apache is coming into play on yours though.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am voting to close it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards.